# Cakephp Deployment to web hosting Missing Helpers Error

Tags: cakephp, hosting

Its my first time using cakephp to deploy in web hosting and i already configured the database  and now it's connected. my homepage and css display correctly but when i press login i won't get to the login form, istead get an error of missing helper. It instructed me to make an urlHelper.php in the src/view/helper. After i created it i get a lot of warning.

for instance this kind of warning.

Warning (512) : Method App\View\Helper\urlHelper::image does not exist [in /home/vol1_7/infinityfree.com/if0_35085963/htdocs/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/Helper.php, line 103]

it would be helpful to me if someone could give me an advice to this problem. Thank you so much!

i Configured the database connection on app_local in the confi. i was expecting that after i config the database it will all run fine.